How to exclude multiple directories from chown -R?
I am writing a bash alias to fix permissions that keep getting messed up on my Synology NAS while running Docker. I just need to chown & chmod everything in the /volume1/docker directory except the Synology system folders @eaDir and #recycle.
I've tried every version of the following command I can on here, but nothing has worked so far:
sudo find . \( ! -path '*/@eaDir/*' -o ! -path '*/\#recycle/*' \) -exec chown user:group {} +

The starting point is the current directory. I just need to exclude @eaDir and #recycle and all the files within. Any help?

What is "every version"? Did you try -a instead of -o?

Sorry if I didn't word that well. I meant that I searched around on here for a while and tried a few different things, but haven't been able to figure it out. I did try the -a at one point, but ended up with the same results.

You've got your logic wrong, \( ! -path '*/@eaDir/*' -o ! -path '*/\#recycle/*' \) will match on the files whose path either don't contain /@eaDir/ (such as ./foo/bar, but also ./#recycle/whatever) or don't contain /#recycle/ (such as ./foo/bar but also ./@eaDir/whatever). The only files that are excluded are the ones whose path contains both /@eaDir/ and /#recycle/ (such as ./#recycle/@eaDir/whatever).
Instead, you'd want:
sudo find . ! '(' -path '*/@eaDir/*' -o -path '*/#recycle/*' ')' \
            -exec chown -h user:group {} +

Or:
sudo find . ! -path '*/@eaDir/*' \
            ! -path '*/#recycle/*' \
            -exec chown -h user:group {} +

Or:
sudo find . -path '*/@eaDir/*' -o \
            -path '*/#recycle/*' -o \
            -exec chown -h user:group {} +

Also note the -h so that for files of type symlink, it's the symlink that is updated, instead of its target (which could be inside some #recycle or @eaDir but also in the system!).
That method is still unsafe as there's a race window between find finding the files and chown being started and changing their ownership during which a user of the system could replace a directory component with a symlink to a system/sensitive directory. Using -execdir instead of -exec if your system supports it would help (but would take longer as chown would need to be run many more times, at least once per directory).
Also beware it will still chown the @eaDir and #recycle directories themselves if not the files within and will still descend into them and find all files in there if not executing chown on them.
Better would likely be:
find . '(' -name @eaDir -o -name '#recycle' ')' -prune -o \
       -exec chown -h user:group {} +

You could also avoid running chown on files that are already owned by user:group:
find . '(' -name @eaDir -o -name '#recycle' ')' -prune -o \
       -user user -group group -o \
       -exec chown -h user:group {} +

As usual a -a is implied when omitted between two predicates (-user user -group group is short for -user user -a -group group), and like in many languages, -a has higher precedence than -o: A -a B -o C -a D is ( A -a B ) -o (C -a D). So if we wanted to be very explicit, we could write the above as:
find .                                          \
  '('                                           \
    '(' -name @eaDir -o -name '#recycle' ')' -a \
    -prune                                      \
  ')' -o '('                                    \
    -user user -a -group group                  \
  ')' -o                                        \
  -exec chown -h user:group {} +


Oh thank you for all of this. I'm still learning some of this stuff, and the find function seems to work in reverse to how I think it should... trying to reprogram my brain. I'm going to give these a shot and see if I can get it to sink in.
